# Minus operation in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a minus operation so far it is going good but I have one question that I can't figure out.

```
SELECT freedays_id,freedays,us.username, year,
       TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(freedays*86400), '%H:%i') AS Total freeydays,
       TIME_FORMAT(SUM(TIMEDIFF(time_till,time_from)), '%H:%i') AS Used freeydays(hours),
       TIME_FORMAT(SUM( TIMEDIFF( time_till, time_from )) - SEC_TO_TIME( freedays*86400 ) , '%H:%i' ) AS remaining freedays(hours)
       FROM " . TBL_freedays. " AS vr
       JOIN " . TBL_users. " AS us ON us.id = vr.id
       LEFT JOIN " . TBL_hours. " AS ur ON ur.id= vr.id
            WHERE
            ur.project_id = 10
            AND
            us.id= vr.id
            AND
            jaar = YEAR(CURDATE())
            AND
            YEAR(datum) = YEAR(CURDATE())
            GROUP BY vr.userid
```

If I run this query the result will be :

1. username = Employee 1
2. Year = 2017
3. Freedays = 19
4. Total freeydays = 456:00
5. Used freeydays(hours) = 06:00
6. remaining freedays(hours) = -450:00

But the remaining free days(hours) = -450:00 and I want it to be 450:00

```
TIME_FORMAT(SUM( TIMEDIFF( time_till, time_from )) - SEC_TO_TIME( freedays*86400 ) , '%H:%i' ) AS remaining freedays(hours)
```

This is the MySQL for it I tried to turn the query around but it didn't work for me so if anybody can help that would be great!

Comment: If the calculation (math wise) is the same then you can use the ABS function to get the positive value.

Comment: I can't use that becuase if the user took more freedays then they have then it has to go -01:00 for example

Answer (score 0):

If total freedays = 456:00 and used freedays(hours) = 06:00

When you subtract **freedays** from **used freedays**, the result will be -450:00.

I don't understand what you meant with 'turning the query around', but when I do  `TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME( freedays*86400 ) - SUM( TIMEDIFF( time_till, time_from )), '%H:%i' ) AS remaining freedays(hours)` I get the correct response

Comment: i copied your anwser and i get an MySQL error : Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'TIME_FORMAT'

Comment: Sorry, I ended up pasting a wrong version where the TIME_FORMAT function was in the worng place. Can you try it now?

Comment: No problem i saw it when i tested it. now it works thanks for helping appreciated (-: